Is NO_DATA_NEEDED exception deterministic?
I was reading about pipelined table functions and was wondering whether one can rely on NO_DATA_EXCEPTION beeing thrown at a predictable point in the procedure.
I have created the following type and procedure:
create or replace type pok_pip_t as table of number;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pok_pip RETURN pok_pip_t PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.ENABLE(NULL);
   FOR indx IN 1..1000 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(indx);
      PIPE ROW (1);
      dbms_output.put_line(indx||'x');
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END;

Now, when I run
DECLARE
v_pok NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(column_value) INTO v_pok FROM pok_pip() WHERE ROWNUM < 10;
END;
/

I see the output
1
1x
2
2x
3
3x
4
4x
5
5x
6
6x
7
7x
8
8x
9

meaning the procedure stopped at the last needed PIPE ROW invocation. Can I rely on this being the case?
EDIT: I of course mean NO_DATA_NEEDED exception.

You're not throwing a NO_DATA_FOUND exception or any other exception. You're stopping the execution due to ROWNUM < 10, which functions a bit differently than most filters because Oracle has an optimization that actually aborts further row processing when the limit is reached.
Because the function is pipelined, control keeps passing back and forth between the SQL (consuming rows) and the function (producing rows), and so the calling query is able to abort further execution before the function can move on to later loop iterations. The abortion happens at PIPE ROW so you don't see the 9x output as it never got executed.

Oh, so the execution is not even multithreaded? And so to my question, is it deterministic? Can I rely on 9x to never be printed?

@Zahrada, it is not multithreaded, it is serial. Yes, the above query would be deterministic. However be aware that dbms_output is for debugging only, it isn't a proper mechanism for returning anything from code except for human reading/logging. Technically determinism refers to the return value(s), which would be the ten rows of COLUMN_VALUE with value 1 in each of them. But in your case, the dbms_output content would be stable as well, assuming that your client always gets the dbms output and prints it (that's controlled by the client, not the database).

Thank you for your answer, it has been most helpful. I understand, that dbms_output is for debugging only, I just wanted to create a function with some side effects. I have however one last question. You said, that dbms_output would be stable as well, but I have read somewhere, that Oracle might use batches for retrieving data from a pipeliend function. Will it be deterministic even then?

@Zahrada, if they ever did do that then the possibility exists for non-determinism with respect to dbms_output, but as that is not the actual output/return value of the function, no rule is being violated if that were to happen.  I have seen other places where code executed more than expected, like passing an object from SQL to a function and the function executes once per attribute of the object instead of once for the entire object. Don't make assumptions about how many times code is called - just code in a way that it accomplishes the task at hand and returns the correct value each time.
